# `margin: 0;` not working on child divs

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems to remove the margin of child divs. I'd like to have the squares defined at `#overview > div` next to next.

```css
#overview {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0em;
  padding: 0em;
  background: green;
}

#overview > div {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

div.type1 {
  background: #990099;
}

div.type2 {
  background: #000080;
}
div.type3 {
  background: #734d26;
}

div.type4 {
  background: #990000;
}
```

```html
<div id="overview">
  <div class="type4"></div>
  <div class="type2"></div>
  <div class="type4"></div>
  <div class="type2"></div>
  <div class="type3"></div>
  <div class="type2"></div>
  <div class="type2"></div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6aum8pn1/)

I'd like to find a solution without floating the squares, and without setting negative margins!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: are you talking about the black border at the bottom of the divs?

Comment: @midda25 no, I'm talking about the space between the squares, the border is okay.

Comment: Ah sorry...im sure this is a browser rendering issue and will be different/consistent between different browsers. What is wrong with floating the divs?

Comment: @midda25  the problem is that I don't know the number of squares. If I float them the  html below the `#overview` will come trough. Then I'll  need to use javascript to fix the problem I guess.

Comment: For the space between elements, see [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239/1529630). For the space below them, see [Image inside div has extra space below the image](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5804256/1529630)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser is interpreting your newlines as blanks, and that's why it's adding spacing. Try removing them (it will be unreadable, but it will fix it without changing any css). The html:

```
<div id="overview">
    <div class="type4"></div><div class="type2"></div><div class="type4"></div><div class="type2"></div><div class="type3"></div><div class="type2"></div><div class="type2"></div>
</div>
```

And your css:

```
#overview {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
    background: green;
}

#overview > div {
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

div.type1 {
    background: #990099;
}

div.type2 {
    background: #000080;
}
div.type3 {
    background: #734d26;
}

div.type4 {
    background: #990000;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6aum8pn1/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use

```css
#overview {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0em;
  padding: 0em;
  background: green;
  flex-direction:row;
}

#overview > div {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

div.type1 {
  background: #990099;
}

div.type2 {
  background: #000080;
}
div.type3 {
  background: #734d26;
}

div.type4 {
  background: #990000;
}
```

```html
<div id="overview">
  <div class="type4"></div>
  <div class="type2"></div>
  <div class="type4"></div>
  <div class="type2"></div>
  <div class="type3"></div>
  <div class="type2"></div>
  <div class="type2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't add float left in your `#overview > div`, as below. Now set your margin value as you want them to be.

```css
#overview > div {
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: `I'd like to find a solution without floating the squares`

Comment: @MoshFeu there are many method, but it's up-to your goal what you want to achieve, I preferred float left because it give me more option of aligning my div, you can even try by implementing negative value to your margin and setting your #overview height. #overview{height:26px;} #overview > div{margin:0px -2px} or as given in above solutions by elad.chen and wikiti :-)

Comment: I preferred floating too, or flexbox. I agree it's better but the fellow specifically ask not to use floating. I don't know why. Maybe he dons't know the `clearfix` trick or something.

Comment: Yes agree maybe he don't know....

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "vertical-align: middle;" to your child elements ( your divs )

```css
#overview {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0em;
  padding: 0em;
  background: green;
}

#overview > div {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

div.type1 {
  background: #990099;
}

div.type2 {
  background: #000080;
}
div.type3 {
  background: #734d26;
}

div.type4 {
  background: #990000;
}
```

```html
<div id="overview">
  <div class="type4"></div>
  <div class="type2"></div>
  <div class="type4"></div>
  <div class="type2"></div>
  <div class="type3"></div>
  <div class="type2"></div>
  <div class="type2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `vertical-align: middle` fixed the vertical spacing, and setting the divs next to next like @Wikiti said fixed the right space. Thanks :)